# Magento getting specific category id from product

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently using the following snippet to get my category ID for each product.

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    echo $category->getName();
    echo $category->getUrlPath();
 }
```

I have then been passing the result of that into a switch to identify the category name.

My problem is that I have just added a sale category that some products will be put into, and the result of

```
echo $category->getName();
```

is the sale category and not the "actual" category it is in.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to make it a) ignore the sale category, b) get next category id stored for the product?, c) make it work some other way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are your products listed on multiple categories besides the sale category ?

Comment: theres a main category for the brand, then the option of two additional categories one being sale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what is the goal, but you can do something like

```
if ($category->getName == 'Sales') {
    continue;
}
```

or `array_filter` $categoryIds excluding `Sales` category

Comment: I was using the ID to get the cat name and sending the cat name into a switch to adjust the font colour of the name. only problem is if something is in sale it brings sale up instead of the range name. I have tried using the continue method but it doesnt get the actual range name, just skips the items on sale.

Comment: Can you please post details on what you are doing? The sample code where you list your categories. There might be an easier solution